# Error on acessing second row of two dimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I have a two dimensional javascript array which needs to get it's first column data `([j][0])` from the entries of a one dimensional array containing street addresses.

A combined string is taken from the DOM which PHP inserts in a previous function. The string then is split into a one dimensional array which contains all the street addresses I want to show on Google Maps. The two dimensional array named "markers" is to be used by Google Maps javascript API.

The array contains as many rows as the street addresses and three columns: the first for the street address, the second for the latitude and the the third for the longitude.

So here is my problem: Since Google Maps isn't showing any map markers on the map, I am trying to debug the code by adding `alert("markers[j][0]: " + markers[j][0]);` in the for loop in order to view each row of the loop (each street address).

The first entry `(markers[0][0])` shows correctly but the second entry `(markers[1][0]` is not alerted to the browser at all. I suspect the the error/problem is after `alert("j: " + j);` in the loop because the rest of the javascript program is not run at all after this loop. (I have some more alerts after this loop and some code to render the map but it isn't run).

Here is my code which contains the error. Please help because I'm trying to fix this issue for two days now and it's driving me nuts.

```
if(document.getElementById('address-target'))
{
 var div = document.getElementById("address-target");

 LocationAddressesCombined = div.textContent;

 alert("Location addresses combined: " + LocationAddressesCombined);
}


var LocationAddresses = LocationAddressesCombined.split(',');

alert("LocationAddresses[0]: " + LocationAddresses[0]);
alert("LocationAddresses[1]: " + LocationAddresses[1]);



var MarkersColumns = ["",0,0];
var markers  = [[MarkersColumns]];


alert("LocationAdresses.length" + LocationAddresses.length);

var j;

//Loop through the "markers" array entries and assign to them the location addresses.
for (j=0; j < LocationAddresses.length; j++)
{
  alert("j: " + j);

  markers[j][0] = LocationAddresses[j];

  alert("markers[j][0]: " + markers[j][0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `markers[j]` has to be an array before you put something into the 0th element of it. Try this:

```
markers[j] = [];
markers[j][0] = LocationAddresses[j];
```

By the way, I'm not sure what you intended to accomplish with these lines:

```
var MarkersColumns = ["",0,0];
var markers  = [[MarkersColumns]];
```

...but that actually sets up a 3-D array where `markers[0][0][0]` is `""`, `markers[0][0][1]` is `0`, and `markers[0][0][2]` is `0`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it worked like a charm. But I wonder, isn't markers already an array since I declared it  with 'var MarkersColumns = ["",0,0]; var markers  = [[MarkersColumns]];'? I'm confused...

Comment: `markers` is already an array, but `markers[j]` for any value of `j` isn't necessarily an array. You have to keep in mind that there aren't any "true" 2-D arrays in JavaScript. You get the effect of a 2-D array by making an array of arrays. All `var markers = [[MarkersColumns]]` accomplishes is making the 0th element of the outer array an array, it doesn't set up arrays in any of the higher indices. PS: If my answer worked for you, can you please up-vote it? :)

Comment: Thank you, your comment was also very helpful to help me understand the issue. I upvoted your answer. So any idea how to declare a 2D array with a variable number of rows (outer array) and predefined number of columns (inner array)?

Comment: There's no way to force that each row of the array has the same number of columns -- you can create what's called a "ragged" array -- but instead of setting each new row to `[]` before you use it, you could set a new row to something like `Array(10)` to make each row start out with 10 columns.